# 3D Touch Quick Action Won't work swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, 3dtouch

I am trying to add 3D touch quick action in my app. I have two viewContollers embedded in navigationContoller. When the user press on the 3D action, it should take them to the add events viewController. But i am getting this error

> could not cast value of type 'Morning_Star_2.AddEventsViewController' (0x1000a2260) to 'UINavigationController' (0x1a79cd360).
>   2017-05-02 02:51:36.220324-0400 Morning Star 2[3731:895126] Could not cast value of type 'Morning_Star_2.AddEventsViewController' (0x1000a2260) to 'UINavigationController' (0x1a79cd360).

Here is my code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.krp.addEvent" {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addEventVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addEventVC") as! UINavigationController
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(addEventVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**I tried changing as! UINavigationController to as! AddEventsViewController. It works, but then it won't show the navigation bar on the top on my add viewController as it normally would if you open the app normally.**

[Here is my main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eVne.png)

Comment: can You show your storyboard images ?

Comment: it is there @BhupatBheda. Please click on the "Here is my main.storyboard"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't cast `AddEventsViewController` to `UINavigationController`, because it isn't `UINavigationController`, is just subclass of `UIViewController`. But as I see, your `rootViewController` is. So you need to cast it to `UINavigationController`, and then push your `AddEventsViewController`, instead present, and you will see `NavigationBar`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if shortcutItem.type == "com.krp.addEvent" {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addEventVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addEventVC") as! AddEventsViewController
        if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            navigationController.pushViewController(addEventVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @blueren, something like this?
 if so, i am getting an error: self.window?.rootViewController?.push(addEventVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Could you please explain it through code?